# how to maintain gridview row color on postback

Tags: c#, gridview, colors

I have a gridview in which i have some coloumns according to

> 8 cell text

i want to change the color of entire row i have done this part but my problem is when i make some search on that page or any postback happen to that page my row color gone

This is code to change color of GridView

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int status = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (status == 1)
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (status == 2)
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
            }
            if (status == 3)
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

On page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.GetData();
        Logs.InsertLogs(Session["DomainID"].ToString(), "User at Report Page", "~/Report.aspx page");
    }
}
private void GetData()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Web_Server", con);
        ad.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // by using rowcreated i get error Input string was not in a correct format. 
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Details not present..!!!');</script>");
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciable... Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding to the [GridView.RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of GridView.RowDataBound, I believe RowCreated is called on postback whereas RowDataBound is only called on databinding.

**EDIT: added sample code**

`<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" RowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">` ...

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  // Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: The link I'd provided had an example already, but I've summarized it in my answer.

Comment: this gives me an error on page_load if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.GetData();            
        } that 'Input string was not in a correct format.' i posted my GetData() in my question

Comment: Can you post the stack trace as well? It'll be available via the Exception you're seeing.

Comment: i get your point i just have to add rowcreated on code behind nothing else rite

Comment: You need the event handler in code behind yes, but then you also need to subscribe to it either by adding it to your GridView on the frontend or do a GridView1.RowCreated+=GridView1_RowCreated somewhere in code behind.  However way you had it previously with RowDataBound will work.

Comment: i just add rowcreated in code behind and in my gridveiw on aspx page and it work thanks mate

Comment: please mark this as the solution/answer if you can, ty :)